# Where to change the value of `lower_case_table_names=2` on windows mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using Windows 10. I am trying to create a tables with the first letter in  the name with uppercase for example: `User`, but I can´t find the file that contains `lower_case_table_names` variable.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is 2 years late but I hope to help others with similar problem.
For those that does not use xampp, the MySQL configuration file should be located at **C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7**.

Alternatively, you can use MySQL Workbench software to change `lower_case_table_names` variable.

1. Run MySQL Workbench software with administration right (Meaning: right click the software icon and "Run as administrator").
2. Connect to your database.
3. Find **Options File** under the left panel (Navigator > Instance > Options File)
4. In **General** tab, tick `lower_case_table_names` to modify the value to 2.
5. Click **Apply** to save the changes.

Credits to [Technology Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOQvfi4LREY)

FYI, remember to restart the MySQL server to reflect the changes!

Comment: Latest version as of October 9, 2018 - Windows 10 - has this path by default: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`

Comment: just a question, lower_case_table_names setting to 2 works like Pascal Format names?

Answer (score 0):

---

### **This option must be set when installing MySQL.**

When I install mysql-8.3.0 (latest at the time of installation); you had to select advance option to select preserve case.

if you didn't select this at that time; later if you directly change in the my.ini file. MySQL would refuse to start.

Answer (score -2):

Do these steps:

1. open your MySQL configuration file: [drive]\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
2. look up for: # The MySQL server [mysqld]
3. add this right below it: lower_case_table_names = 2
4. save the file and restart MySQL service

From: http://webdev.issimplified.com/2010/03/02/mysql-on-windows-force-table-names-to-lowercase/

Comment: i am not using xampp

Comment: this is just an example, search for my.ini or my.cnf file